# how to select the data in Teradata if it has duplicates in it?

Tags: teradata

consider TABLE1 and  has the below records.

```
ID  MBR_ID     STRT_DT       END_DT    ID_TYPE  
1    001      01-01-2019   31-12-2019   TYPE_1
2    002      02-05-2019   31-07-2020   TYPE_1
3    002      03-03-2019   31-12-2020   TYPE_2
4    003      03-03-2019   31-12-2020   TYPE_3
5    003      01-01-2019   31-12-2019   TYPE_4
6    003      13-05-2019   31-12-2020   TYPE_5
```

TABLE2

```
s.no   MBR_ID      DOB
1       001     30-03-2019
2       002     29-05-2019
3       003     01-08-2019
```

I want to fetch the records which satisfies the below conditions:

```
sel * 
from TABLE1 
join TABLE2 on TABLE1.MBR_ID=TABLE2.MBR_ID.MBR_ID 
where TABLE2.DOB between TABLE1.STRT_DT and TABLE2.END_DT
```

- in case of duplicates, pull the ID from TABLE1 which has maximum of `END_DT`
- if there are still duplicates, pull the ID from `TABLE1` which has maximum of `ID`

The result should be like below:

```
ID  MBR_ID     STRT_DT       END_DT    ID_TYPE  
1    001      01-01-2019   31-12-2019   TYPE_1
3    002      03-03-2019   31-12-2020   TYPE_2
6    003      13-05-2019   31-12-2020   TYPE_5
```

I should fetch the `ID` from `TABLE1`. We have 3 different `ID` present for the same `MBR_ID`. But I should fetch the maximum `ID` from `TABLE1` if I have same maximum `END_DT`.

In above table, 3 different `ID` are there for `MBR_ID=003`. So, first I should check if `DOB` lies between `STRT_DT` and `END_DT` of `TABLE1`.

I have 3 rows which satisfies the same. So I need to fetch the row which has high `END_DT`. For this, 2 rows have same high `END_DT`. So I need to fetch the maximum(`ID`) from `TABLE1`.

Comment: *`on TABLE1.MBR_ID=TABLE2.MBR_ID.MBR_ID`* - typo. *`between TABLE1.STRT_DT and TABLE2.END_DT`* - typo (?) too.

Answer (score 1):

Apply a ROW_NUMBER using a Derived Table/CTE in Standard SQL or simplified using Teradata's QULIAFY syntax:

```
select * 
from TABLE1 
join TABLE2 on TABLE1.MBR_ID=TABLE2.MBR_ID 
where TABLE2.DOB between TABLE1.STRT_DT and TABLE2.END_DT
QUALIFY 
   ROW_NUMBER()
   OVER (PARTITION BY TABLE1.MBR_ID    --  for each MBR_ID
         ORDER BY TABLE2.END_DT DESC   --  ID from TABLE1 which has maximum of END_DT
                 ,TABLE1.ID DESC) = 1  --  ID from TABLE1 which has maximum of ID
```